# SARIMAX model not giving prediction according to training set

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, modeling, arima, sarimax

I am doing time series analysis, I have 36 months of data, starting from 09/2019- 03/2023.. the data is aggregated to the monthly level.. I have trained a SARIMAX model.. but the model seems to starting training from 0. I dont know why? I tried different pdq values, but nothing is helping.. this is the acf plot
[acf plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2VGc.png) hence I am choosing the q value as 13
this is the pacf plot
[pacf plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVwP3.png) hence I am choosing the p value as 13.
This is how I am training the model
model_new=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(pivot_train,order=(13, 0, 13), seasonal_order=(0,0,0,12))
sarima_model=model_new.fit()
forecast_df  = sarima_model.predict(start='2022-10-01',end ='2023-05-01')
this is how the residuals look like
[residual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU5Dk.png)

This graph shows the training, testing, forecasted and model fit..
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdfJt.png)

My model is starting the fit from 0.. My questions..

1. The model is starting fitting from 0? why ? and how can I change that ?
2. the model is capturing the peak in training at Jan but predicted value tells another story? why ? how can I improve?

I tried changing the pdq values, I tried auto_arima, I tried arima.. nothing seems to work..
I also tried log transformation and differencing technique.